# Android - Intent "putExtra"

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the next code:

```
´
ArrayList<Integer> vc = new ArrayList<Integer>; vc.add(1); vc.add(2);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(class1.this, class2.class);
myIntent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("Key", vc);
```

´
the class2 receive correctly the arraylist, but...
After I use the next code: (basically the same)

```
´
ArrayList<Integer> vc = new ArrayList<Integer>; vc.add(10); vc.add(20);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(class1.this, class2.class);
myIntent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("Key", vc);
´
```

My second class received again the first ArrayList with 1 and 2 values

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not instantiating arrayList
`ArrayList<Integer> vc = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
so it is using old values